# dynamic classes with tailwindcss and eleventy

Tags: javascript, frontend, tailwind-css, postcss, eleventy

I am using eleventy.js with tailwindcss and postcss. In my setup, postcss does not seem to recognise dynamic classes like

```
md:pl-{{(loop.length-loop.index+1)*2}}
```

And so I never get them in the final css file.
my `package.json` file has the following

```js
"predev": "rimraf tmp && mkdir -p tmp/assets/css",
"dev": "npm run watch:css && npm run watch:app",
"watch:app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development eleventy --input=src --output=tmp --serve",
"watch:css": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development postcss src/assets/css/tailwind.css > tmp/assets/css/style.css"
```

my postcss config looks like so

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

I am using postcss for tailwindcss along with eleventyjs, and so the `loop` comes from a `nunjuncks` for loop but the class doesn't show up in the css file generated by tailwind.  Is there any way around this?

```html
<a href="{{ title | url }}">
  {% set title = title.split('') %}
    <div class="text-lg md:text-xl uppercase flex flex-row justify-between md:justify-end">
      {% for letter in title %}
        <p class="md:pl-{{(loop.length-loop.index+1)*2}}">
          <span> {{ letter }} </span>
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tailwind v3.0 or later, or Tailwind 2 with the JIT compiler enabled, you can ["safelist" the classes you're using](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...

  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /pl-\d+/,
      variants: ['md'],
    },
  ],

  // ...
}
```

This will keep all `pl` utilities in your output CSS, regardless of whether they exist in the source. If you have more information on how long `title` can be and therefore which classes will be generated, then it's possible to be more specific in your regular expression.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...

  safelist: [
    {
      // for example only, adjust this depending on your output
      pattern: /pl-(-2|0|2|4|6|8)/,
      variants: ['md'],
    },
  ],

  // ...
}
```